# JSON stringify still returns [object Object] in JS

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json

I have a little problem with stringify. 
I am passing variable from Java to JavaScript. 
In Java after out.println(strin); it looks like this:

```
[{"date":"01-18-2015"},{"date":"01-19-2015"},{"date":"01-21-2015"},{"date":"01-19-2015"},{"date":"01-19-2015"},{"date":"01-19-2015"}]
```

So I am trying to pass it to JavaScript

```
var obj = new String(<%= strin %>); 
var tekst = JSON.stringify(obj);
alert(tekst);
```

But this alert still gives me [object Objetc],[object Object] etc. 
However if I am putting that dates straightly to JS variable like this:

```
var zmienna = '[{"date":"01-18-2015"},{"date":"01-19-2015"},{"date":"01-21-2015"},{"date":"01-19-2015"},{"date":"01-19-2015"},{"date":"01-19-2015"}]';
```

stringify works good. 
Im really confused about this. Can anyone give me some tips?

My code for json in Java looks like this:

```
String next_date = "";
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
        while (daty.next()) {
            next_date = formatter.format(daty.getDate("date"));
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("date", next_date);
            json.put(obj);
        }

        String strin = json.toString();
```

Comment: `new String` is an object. You should use a string literal. Perhaps `var obj = <%= strin %>`

Answer (score 0):

It is the JSON notation (JavaScript Object Notation) that you taking advantage of.

When you declare a variable this way:

```
var zmienna = '[{"date":"01-18-2015"},{"date":"01-19-2015"},..];
```

you basically declare an `array[]` with elements that are `objects{}`.

It is equivalent to below code.

```
var firstDate = new Date("01-18-2015");
var secondDate =new Date("01-19-2015");
var zmienna = [firstDate, secondDate];
```

This is ready to use array, while in the other code you declare a String variable with some characters in it.

```
var obj = new String(<%= string %>);
```

I hope it clarified you understanding.

Comment: BTW it is common habit to use English names for a variable.